# Qgis2web rule-based symbology issue

Tags: qgis2web

first post on this website I'm referring to 100 times a day, very exciting :-)
Just wondering if conditionnal formatting (simple colour fill, based on an attribute string evaluation in my case) is supported in a leaflet export? I saw in another post that a limited number of expressions are supported, I've used CASE, but I guess I could use a few concatenated IF's if that's needed?
[image: problem !!]

Comment: Hi Will_KB, welcome to GIS SE. Great to have you here! Qgis2web works great for standard styling, however, advanced styling options most often do not work, at least not 1:1. QGIS rendering machine is something completely different than web rendering by Leaflet or Openlayers and the plugin has limited capacities to "translate". So I guess there is a lot of manual adapting necessary to create a webmap looking similar as in QGIS. However, if you want to have a webmap looking 1:1 like in your QGIS project, have a look at qgis cloud: https://qgiscloud.com/ - install the plugin & publish your map.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I guess for this specific project that's been published and is being used already I'm a bit taken by time so I'll just create a group with separate layers it'll be faster. I've tried QGIS Cloud free in the past and got quickly limited by the 50MB cap for background layers. We're a Burning Man affiliated non for profit organisation and can't afford a monthly license unfortunately :-)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to try is a categorized renderer. While qgis2web support for dynamic styles is limited (as you say, only a tiny subset of expressiom functions are supported), if all you need is to set styles depending on attribute values, that should be exactly what a categorized renderer achieves.

There is every chance that your requirements are more complex, but I'd definitely try to get a categorized renderer to do the heavy lifting for you.